# boost::file_system::create_directory doesn't create directory, yet ErroCode is SUCCESS

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-filesystem

So, I am using a simple code like

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
if (!boost::filesystem::create_directory(out_path.parent_path(), ec)) {
    std::cerr << "couldn't create directory\n";
    std::cerr << ec.message() << "\n";
    return -1;
}
```

I am trying to create directory passing absolute file path as `out_path`. The result is, I get into if branch, and the ec.message() returns Success. 
I have all rights over the `out_path` directory, read, write, execute whatsoever.

I am completely pissed of. I can create the directory with the same very path right from bash, but I cannot using the c++ code I have written. 
There is no fail however, when I pass relative pass as `out_path`, like "temp", and directory gets created from where the c++ program is run.

Help me please, I really don't understand whats goin on here :(

Comment: "I have all rights over the out_path directory" I'm confused, is out_path existed?

Comment: And why don't you use create_directories instead of create_directory?

Comment: The `out_path` doesn't exist, but `out_path.parent_path()` does.
I also tried to use `create_directories` with same result


UPD `out_path.parent_path().parent_path()` exists, `out_path.parent_path()` does not

Comment: then out_path.parent_path() is existed, why do want to create it again?

Comment: Sorry, I am imprecise. It also doesn't exist.

Say, I have /A/B/C, then out_path is /A/B/C/D/file. I want to create D under /A/B/C, which exists.

Comment: Ok, i have figured something out 
I am trying to create directory using `boost::filesystem::path`, and it fails. 
I hardcode the very same path as `char *`, and I succeed. Weird.

Comment: Have you tried to print that path

Comment: You know what? My path contains subfolder named 0. This means, I have path like .../0/... and somewhy it turns out the path is trimmed to that very 0! I don't know whether it is a std::string problem or boost, but what I see now is that even though `out_path.c_str()` is identical to `char *` variant when printed, they have different strlen!

Comment: They have different strlen, that's the problem. Try to hex-dump it, I doubt that there's some Unicode value in your path.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I indeed used extra parent_path()!
Danh, excuse me so much for taking your time!

Answer (score 3):

When `create_directory` returns false it means it did not create the directory. The most likely reason for that is that the directory already exists! In that case it would return false, but not set the `error_code`.

The code in your question assumes if the function returns false then an error happened, but that's wrong. False just means it didn't create it.

Comment: ok, so it basically doesn't create the directory and gives you no reason why? Only STL designers geniuses make such APIs.

Comment: The design comes from Boost, not the STL, and not the C++ standard library, so direct your snark elsewhere please.